# What are the FPS of the FaceTime Camera for the iPhone 6S vs 7+ vs X vs iPad Pro?

Tags: iphone, ipad, video, facetime

We are capturing video from iOS devices and processing it using OpenGL but are encountering a FPS difference between the devices when trying to set them at their maximum rate.

The iPhone 6S and iPad Pro FaceTime cameras are maxing at 60 fps.

The 7+ and iPhone X however are maxing at 30 fps.

It seems unusual that the FPS would decrease with later versions of Apple's hardware. We are trying to figure out if this is a software issue or simply the technical specifications for the frame rate for the FaceTime camera.

We looked on Apple's technical specifications page but the frame rates of the FaceTime cameras aren't listed (though the rear cameras are.) For example:
https://www.apple.com/iphone-6s/specs/
https://www.apple.com/iphone-x/specs/

What are the FPS of the FaceTime Camera for the iPhone 6S vs 7+ vs X vs iPad Pro?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the beginning of an answer.

We found a private library method of Apple's (not allowed in the app store) called CAMCaptureCapabilities which has a read only property called front1080pMaxFPS.

We were able to run this on an iPhone X and found the front camera maximum to be **30fps**.

On the iPhone 6S/6S+ we have an app that is able to set the camera to **60fps**.

We still need to test on other phone models to see their maximum (i.e. particular iPhone 7 and 8.)

**Interestingly, this means the iPhone X's front camera *is* slower than an iPhone 6S/6S+.**

Answer (score 0):

The camera used for FaceTime on an iPhone is the front camera, often referred to as the *secondary* camera. The main camera is often referred to as the *primary* camera.

In terms of the secondary camera of the various iPhone models you're asking about, the frames per second ratings are the same for all of them: 1080p@30fps or 720p@240fps.

Where these cameras differ are in their other specs (e.g. the iPhone 6s has a 5MP camera, while the iPhone 7 has a 7MP camera.

Comment: I think that's only technically correct for end users as certain devices have other settings for their cameras. For example, we have an app in the app store that runs both the iPhone 6S/6S+ and the iPad Pro front cameras at 60fps.